# Links in Subject Index

Tags: beamer, indexing, imakeidx

How can I do `\printindex` with clickable links ?

```
\documentclass[mathserif,12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\newenvironment{theindex}{}{}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeatletter

\def\@idxitem{\par}

\def\imki@firstpagestyle{empty}

\makeatother

\makeindex    

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\index{task}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\printindex

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not tested, but have you tried something with `hyperref`?

Comment: @JouleV I do believe that beamer already loads hyperref, but might do so with special options